# How does the actionCreator, props, and component connect in React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; //this is a single connect property
import { selectBook } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class BookList extends Component {
  renderList() {
    return this.props.books.map(book => {
      return (
        <li key={book.title} className="list-group-item"> {book.title} </li>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    books: state.books
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  // Whenver selectBook is called, the result should be passed to all of the reducers.
  // selectBook value is an actionCreator, a function.
  return bindActionCreators({ selectBook: selectBook }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList)
```

and

```
export function selectBook(book) {
  console.log("A book has been seelcted:", book.title)
}
```

The parts that I don't understand are this:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList)
```

What is going on? Is this part responsible for making the state and the dispatch method available to the component `BookList`?

What is this function doing:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  // Whenver selectBook is called, the result should be passed to all of the reducers.
  // selectBook value is an actionCreator, a function.
  return bindActionCreators({ selectBook: selectBook }, dispatch)
}
```

Are these built in redux functions? What are they returning? What is going on? What is `dispatch`?

The value `selectBook` on the right side is a function right? So I guess it gets called, and the return value will flow through the reducers via the dispatch method? But then what is `bindActionCreators` doing?

How are props made available inside the component `BookList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many questions and how hard we try to explain it what is going on here probably confuses you more. I strongly advise you to watch those two videos from the creator of Redux:

[Getting started with Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)
and
[Idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux)

Those vidoes explain what is Redux, how does its pieces get together. So, before following any other tutorials first grasp Redux itself.

Also, Redux's [official documentation](https://redux.js.org/) is great, if you follow it alongside with the videos would be great for your study.

But, let me answer your questions anyway.

**First question**

> The parts that I don't understand are this:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList)
```

> What is going on? Is this part responsible for making the state and
>   the dispatch method available to the component BookList?

**Answer**

`connect` here is provided by `react-redux` package, not `redux` itself. It is a helper higher order function used to open your state and action creators to your components. So, you guessed right. This is how people generally connect their components into the store to get state and dispatch (to use action creators).

**Second question**

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  // Whenver selectBook is called, the result should be passed to all of the reducers.
  // selectBook value is an actionCreator, a function.
  return bindActionCreators({ selectBook: selectBook }, dispatch)
}
```

> Are these built in redux functions? What are they returning? What is
>   going on? What is dispatch?
>
> The value selectBook on the right side is a function right? So I guess
>   it gets called, and the return value will flow through the reducers
>   via the dispatch method? But then what is bindActionCreators doing?
>
> How are props made available inside the component BookList?

**Answer**

No, they are not built in Redux functions as I explained in the first answer. `mapStateToProps` opens your state to your component and feed it as props. So, if you open any state to your component with `connect` and `mapStateToProps` you get this state as props. In your example you get the `books` state from your global state and open this as `books` to your component. Then this component gets this as `this.props.books`.

`mapDispatchToProps` opens your action creator functions to your component as props. There a couple of ways using this, `bindActionCreators` is one of them but actually you don't need it here. It is good for getting state if you need it while you are dispatching or passing your action creators to a child component which does not aware of Redux. So, `bindActionCreators` is not a good start to understand `mapDispatchToProps`.

Basically it is like that:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  someFunction: () => dispatch(someFunction())
})
```

Here you are opening your `someFunction()` action creator to your component as the name `someFunction`. You can use a different name or you can do other staff here and then `dispatch` your action creator according to this. But in this example you are not doing anything extra, just dispatching the action creator. So, there is a shorthand for this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    someFunction,
}
```

Yes, for this situation this does the same thing. Even, there is a shorter one:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {someFunction})(Component)
```

Without using a `mapDispatchToProps` you can use your action creators like this, then get as props in your components.

Also (yes there is more :)) event without using any function argument in connect, we can use action creators.

```
connect()(Component)
connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```

If we skip `mapDispatchToProps` like one of the methods above, `dispatch` is automatically passed to the component props. Then, we can use it like any other prop to dispatch our action creator:

```
this.props.dispatch(someFunction())
```

For your example it goes like this (I know this app, so I'm using real action creator example here).

You can write `mapDispatchToProps` like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ( {
  selectBook: book => dispatch( selectBook( book ) ),
} );
```

Here you use `selectBook` as `this.props.selectBook` in your component and dispatch an action. You see actually your prop fires a function and it dispatches your real action creator here. Remember, action creators returns objects and those objects need to be dispatched in order to go through reducers. So, you are dispatching your action creator (which is returned by `selectBook`.

Now, with `bindActionCreators` without using its real advantages you can write it as:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    bindActionCreators( { selectBook: selectBook }, dispatch )
);
```

or with some ES6 shorthand for object keys which has the same name:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    bindActionCreators( { selectBook }, dispatch )
);
```

This is slightly shorter than the first one. You don't need to point a function and dispatch it. You gave the action creator to `bindActionCreators` and it does the job for you.

Now, the shorter one since you are just dispatching:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  selectBook,
};
```

Even without `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
connect( mapStateToProps, { selectBook } )( BookList )
```

So, `Provider`, `connect` are being provided by `react-redux` to make the life easier for us. `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are the functions which `connect` waits. Names are not important, we can use any name for them but these are the defacto ones everyone uses. The order is important and if we want to skip `mapStateToProps` we must use `null` in its place like:

```
connect( null, mapDispatchToProps )( Component )
```

Without `connect` actually we can use `store` and what it contains `getState`, `dispatch`, `subscribe` in any component with two ways:

- Don't use `react-redux` and pass the `store` as prop all the way down to each component you want to use. Then reach it via `this.props.store`.
- Use `react-redux`'s `Provider`, then use `context` for the component to get the `store`.

As you can imagine passing the store all the way down to components is a nightmare.

To use `store` with `context` first you need to specify the `contextTypes` of the component:

```
BookList.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

After doing that you can grab store from `this.context.store` and use `getState` to get the state or `dispatch` to dispatch your action creators.

Here how our component would be if we didn't use `connect`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { selectBook } from "../actions/index";

class BookList extends Component {
  renderList() {
    return this.context.store.getState().books.map( book =>
      ( <li
        key={book.title}
        onClick={() => this.context.store.dispatch( selectBook( book ))}
      >
        {book.title}
      </li> ) );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

BookList.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default BookList;
```

Here we use: `this.context.store.getState().books` instead of `this.props.books` and `this.context.store.dispatch( selectBook( book ))` instead of `this.props.selectBook( book )`. As you can see we can reach state and can dispatch our action creators with this way. But with `connect` and its flexibility we open our state and action creators in a nice and clean way.

Comment: I see so the `connect` function is what is making the state available as props in the component.

Comment: will the shorthand notations still dispatch the action to the reducers? There's no use of `dispatch` in the shorthand notations.

Comment: Yes, `connect` does that but I've updated my answer and tried to explain how we can do that without using `connect`. For the last question, shorthand automatically does that for us. No need to use any `dispatch` explicitly.

Comment: It's excellent with a few typos. Mind fixing them? Other than that, your post is excellent.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jwan622. Please, feel free to fix any typo or even the language itself since I'm not a native English speaker.