# What is going on in this Redux code...confused about mapDispatchToProps, dispatch, and connect

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a react tutorial and I had a few questions.

I am confused about this function:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchWeather }, dispatch)
}
```

I want to breakdown each part of this function.

How do you hook up the action creator to a container? How is `this.props.fetchWeather` working code? Is this responsible for that?:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
```

If so, what is this doing?

```
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchWeather }, dispatch)
```

Is that responsible for making sure that the action object that is returned from the action creator flows down into the middleware and reducers?

What is this doing then:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
```

Is `mapDispatchToProps` just convention or is it part of react?

Lastly, what is this export doing:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

What is the connect doing? What does it do for me?

```
Here is my whole code for reference:


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchWeather } from '../actions/index';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { term: '' };

    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  onFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.fetchWeather(this.state.term);
    this.setState({ term: '' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="input-group">
        <input
          placeholder="Get a five-day forecast in your favorite cities"
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />

        <span className='input-group-btn'>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchWeather }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Comment: Does not this answer cover your questions? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51461567/7060441 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *A very concise answer would be:*

- `mapStateToProps()` is a utility which helps your component gets updated state(which is updated by some other components)
- `mapDispatchToProps()` is a utility which will help your component to fire an action event (dispatching action which may cause a change of application state)
- `bindActionCreators()` is mostly used when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that *isn't aware of Redux*, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.
- `<Provider>` makes the Redux store available to the your "connected" React components.
- `connect()` is a  higher-order component (HOC) that lets you inject Redux state into a regular React component.

---

### *Let's dive a bit deeper*

**ReactJS -** `JS` library for building user interfaces.
**Redux -** `JS` library for managing application state.

### Putting them together using `react-redux`:

If we want to link our `React` application with the `Redux` store, we first have to let our app know that this store exists. This is where we come to the first major part of the `react-redux` library, which is the `Provider`.

A `Provider` is a React component given to us by the `react-redux` library. It serves just one purpose: to “provide” the store to its child components.

### Provider

Makes the Redux store available to the `connect()` calls in the component hierarchy below. Normally, you can’t use `connect()` without wrapping a parent or ancestor component in `<Provider>`. So ultimately `connect` does just that, it connects your `React` app to the `Redux` store.

```
//This is the store we create with redux's createStore method
const store = createStore(todoApp, {})

// Provider is given the store as a prop
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app-node')
)
```

**Props**

- **store** (R*edux Store*): The single Redux store in your application.
- **children** (*React Element*): The root of your component hierarchy.

---

### Explanation and usage of the `Connect` function:

Now that we have “provided” the redux store to our application, we can now connect our components to it. We established previously that there is no way to directly interact with the store. We can either retrieve data by obtaining its current `state` or change its state by dispatching an action (we only have access to the top and bottom component of the redux flow diagram shown previously). This is precisely what `connect()` does.

To use `connect()`, you need to define a special function called `mapStateToProps` that describes how to transform the current `Redux` store state into the props you want to pass to a presentational component you are wrapping.

---

In addition to reading the state, container components can dispatch actions. In a similar fashion, you can define a function called `mapDispatchToProps()` that receives the `dispatch()` method and returns callback props that you want to inject into the presentational component.

---

### Simple explanation and a basic example of `mapStateToProps`

The Store is a box, which contains the entire application state. Imagine that this box is in an unknown location.

The components need to take some of the things out of the box but they only need some of the things stored in it. The components know what they need from the box but they don't know where the box is.

The `mapStateToProps` function is a filter used to select which things in the box are required by the component. The selected things become the component properties.

The `mapStateToProps` function is not enough because it selects the required things in the box but it doesn't know where the box is located.

The `connect` function knows where the box is located and passes it to the mapStateToProps function so it can grab what it needs.

Conclusion: **`mapStateToProps`** simply returns a specified part of the current state. `mapStateToProps` get the data that is fed to its component.

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return { things: state.things }
};
```

So now we're able to use that part of the state as `props` **->** `this.props.things`

---

But what if the component wants to change the state? That is where `mapDispatchToProps` comes in.

### Simple explanation and a basic example of `mapDispatchToProps`

As implied in its name, this function directs the dispatching or sending of an action by pointing it to an action creator. For example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
     return {
          addThing: addThing,
          doAnotherThing: doAnotherThing
     }
}
```

`mapDispatchToProps` takes the `dispatch` functions in your component and executes them against the `Redux reducer` when that function is fired. Remember that Props aren’t just objects, they can also be functions. This is where mapDispatchtoProps applies. MapDispatchToProps allows for you to dispatch state changes to your store. An example would be a button click that triggers a refresh or an automatic loading of data once the component is mounted.

The action creator is made available to the component as a prop, which is usually tied to an event handler function contained in the component:

```
handleOnClick() {
     this.props.addThing();
};
```

However, returning the action creator is only one part. We also want the send that returned `action` to the store. How do we do that? We use Redux’s `bindActionCreators()`.

### Simple explanation and a basic implementation of `bindActionCreators()`:

Turns an object whose values are action creators, into an object with the same keys, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly.

Normally you should just call dispatch directly on your Store instance. If you use Redux with React, react-redux will provide you with the dispatch function so you can call it directly, too.

The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.

**To implement it, we:**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
         addThing: addThing,
         doAnotherThing: doAnotherThing
         }, dispatch);
};
```

The `bindActionCreators()` function accepts the action creator and the store’s dispatch function as arguments, and returns a `dispatch` function that uses the return value of the `action creator` as its arguments.

Once again, tying this all together is the `connect()` function, in which we pass mapDispatchToProps as a second argument. For example:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

which will export a component that can both get the **current state** from the store, and dispatch an action to the store to trigger and **update** to the **state**.

***Now, let's put it all together with a little `TodoItem.js` React functional component:***

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const TodoItem = ({ todo, destroyTodo }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {todo.text}
      <span onClick={destroyTodo}> x </span>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todo: state.todos[0]
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    destroyTodo: () =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'DESTROY_TODO'
      })
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem)
```

`mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are both pure functions that are provided the stores “state” and “dispatch” respectively. Furthermore, both functions have to return an object, whose keys will then be passed on as the props of the component they are connected to.

In this case, `mapStateToProps` returns an object with only one key: “todo”, and `mapDispatchToProps` returns an object with the **`destroyTodo`** key.

***The exported connected component provides `todo` and `destroyTodo` as props to `TodoItem` functional component***

Comment: I like the box analogy.

Comment: @devserkan Thanks. I've read somewhere a similar analogy. I really tried to answer this question as best as I could. I hope it's good and that it will help someone. Have a good one. And thanks again **:)**

Comment: is `mapStateToProps` part of react or can it be named anything?

Comment: It's part of the `react-redux` library and I'll answer your question with a question. Can `componentDidMount` be called something else? **:)**

Comment: From my answer: "So, Provider, connect are being provided by react-redux to make the life easier for us. mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are the functions which connect waits. Names are not important, we can use any name for them but these are the defacto ones everyone uses." And this old question also belongs to OP :) He thanked me there so kindly. @Jwan622, I see that you are confused but just read the answers.

Comment: What I was trying to say is: "That's totally irrelevant". You're the one setting it to a variable, right? Hence `const mapStateToProps = () .... etc ` so you're the one choosing the "name".But it's a standard and by convention, it's named and widely accepted as such **:)**

Comment: `componentDidMount` can't be named something else but it seems like `mapStateToProps` can.

Comment: @Bigga_HD can you clarify this: `mapDispatchToProps takes the dispatch functions in your component and executes them against the Redux reducer when that function is fired. Remember that Props aren’t just objects, they can also be functions. This is where mapDispatchtoProps applies. MapDispatchToProps allows for you to dispatch state changes to your store.`. As written, without the `DisPatch`, the function can't do any of that right?

Comment: What's the action and what's the action creator?

Comment: **`Actions`** are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store. They are the only source of information for the store.  
**`Action creators`** are exactly that —functions that create actions.
I suggest going over the official [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions). Have a good one **:)**